# How calculate importance ratio for continuous states?

Tags: model-evaluation, reinforcement-learning, importance-sampling

I am trying to understand importance sampling estimators, in particular for off-policy evaluation in reinforcement learning.
I am working with the definition:

> The IS estimator provides an unbiased estimate of π_1’s value by averaging the following function of each trajectory `(s_1, a_1, r_1, ..., s_H+1)` in the data: define the per-step importance ratio as `p_t := π_1(a_t|s_t) = π_0(a_t|s_t)`

In words, I understand this as: "how likely π_1 takes action a_t in s_t compared to π_0". But if `s` is continuous and unbounded, how do I get the probability of `a` given `s`? Do I have to fit a model on the `(s,a)` pairs for each policy? (I thought IS was model-free)